# Airflow Dynamic Task Mapping with follow up tasks

Tags: dynamic, airflow, airflow-taskflow

I have a DAG with dynamic task mapping. I wonder how dynamically mapped tasks can have successor task in its own path. Here is a visual representation ( Forgive my sloppiness]

```
        -> Mapped Task B[0] -> Task C
```

Task A -- > -> Mapped Task B[1] -> Task C

```
        -> Mapped Task B[2] -> Task C
```

I am unable to model this flow. Any help is much appreciated

Tried this one. But It waits for all mapped B tasks to complete before it starts any C instances
taskB.expand_kwargs(v=taskA) >> taskC.expand(v=task A)

Doesn't even compile
(Task B >> TaskC).expand_kwargs(Task A)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with **task_group**, as described in documentation:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html#mapping-over-a-task-group

```
import logging

from airflow.decorators import task, task_group
from airflow.models.dag import DAG
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from pendulum import datetime


with DAG(
    dag_id="dynamic_task_group",
    description="Task Group on top of Dynamic Mapped Tasks",
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
    schedule_interval=None,
) as dag:

    @task
    def create_instructions(**kwargs):
        # kwargs if you need an input params
        # input = kwargs.get("params")
        # try:
        #     input_param = input["input_param"]
        return [
            {"pipeline_name": 1, "parameters": 2},
            {"pipeline_name": 3, "parameters": 4},
        ]

    @task
    def print_values(pipeline_name, parameters):
        logging.info(f"pipeline_name: {pipeline_name}")
        logging.info(f"parameters: {parameters}")

    @task_group
    def my_group(pipeline_name, parameters):
        print_values(pipeline_name, parameters) >> EmptyOperator(task_id="done")

    my_group.expand_kwargs(create_instructions())
```

Then, every done task (here I used `EmptyOperator`) will be triggered after every run of `print_values` task.

[image: Airflow UI screenshot]

And if you want to check how it behaves with failed upstream task:

```
    @task
    def print_values(pipeline_name, parameters):
        logging.info(f"pipeline_name: {pipeline_name}")
        logging.info(f"parameters: {parameters}")
        if pipeline_name == 3:
            raise AirflowException("Test error status")

    @task
    def print_values_again(pipeline_name, parameters):
        logging.info(f"pipeline_name: {pipeline_name}")
        logging.info(f"parameters: {parameters}")

    @task_group
    def my_group(pipeline_name, parameters):
        one = print_values(pipeline_name, parameters)
        two = print_values_again(pipeline_name, parameters)

        one >> two

    my_group.expand_kwargs(create_instructions())
```

[image: Airflow UI print_values screenshot]
[image: Airflow UI print_values_again screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Setup of relationship is with `>>`.

You didn't post your code so I'd use example:

```
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG

with DAG(dag_id="example", start_date=datetime(2023, 10, 1)) as dag:
    c = EmptyOperator(task_id="c")
    a = EmptyOperator(task_id="a")

    b = BashOperator.partial(task_id="bash").expand_kwargs(
        [
            {"bash_command": "echo $ENV1", "env": {"ENV1": "1"}},
            {"bash_command": "printf $ENV2", "env": {"ENV2": "2"}},
        ],
    )

    a >> b >> c
```

Gives:

[image]

Where task `bash` is expanded into two mapped tasks:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Elad-Kalif, my requirement is to have a C task running right after b[0] and one more C right after b[1]. In your example, C waits all mapped B tasks to complete and a single instance executes after that

Answer (score -1):

Use `one_success` [trigger rule](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dags.html#concepts-trigger-rules) to start downstream task when one of upstream succeeds.

Given below code:

```
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

with DAG(dag_id="test_expand_deps", start_date=datetime(2023, 10, 1), schedule=None) as dag:
    c = EmptyOperator(task_id="c", trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS)
    a = EmptyOperator(task_id="a")

    @task
    def b(inp=0):
        if(inp > 1):
            raise Exception("Fail")
        print(inp)
        return inp

    a >> b.expand(inp=list(range(0,3))) >> c
```

Results in this flow:
[image]

Or, if you wish, the same with pure taskflow:

```
with DAG(dag_id="eas_test_expand_deps", start_date=datetime(2023, 10, 1), schedule=None) as dag:
    @task
    def a(): return list(range(0,3))

    @task
    def b(inp):
        if(inp > 1):
            raise Exception("Fail")
        print(inp)
        return inp

    @task(trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS)
    def c(inp):
        print(max(inp))

    a_res = a()
    b_res = b.expand(inp=a_res)
    c_res = c(b_res)
```

which behaves in the same manner except that input to `c` will be all successfully executed instances of `b`.

Comment: C task will be triggered if first dynamic task finishes, and there will be just one instance of it: that was not the question. We need tasks that would be run after every dynamic task (so three B dynamic tasks: three C task instances)

Comment: You didn't describe this in your question which clearly states: *But It waits for all mapped B tasks to complete before it starts any C instances*. And you specify a single `TaskC` in your code. How should I guess that you need one instance of pair `taskB` and `taskC` per output of `taskA`?

Comment: it's not my question :) but `I wonder how dynamically mapped tasks can have successor task in its own path` you can understand as every task B needs to have his own downstream task

Comment: OK, but it's possible that I saw already edited question, so maybe this is where our misunderstanding comes from

Comment: @Gignac Oh, of course, I'm sorry for confusion. The approach is the same: to put `B` and `C` inside a task group and then use task group expansion feature. You've already described this in your answer, as I can see.